# how can I aggregate the values from an array of micrometer counters

Tags: java, spring-cloud-stream, confluent-platform, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I’m collecting a series of metrics for a kafka stream application, the issue I have is I’d like a consolidated value for the meters of a specific name. To make this a little clearer, these metrics are presented as an array of n items with n being the number of threads configured for the Kafka Streams application. I must add that I can consolidate the values by adding the sum of the ‘FunctionCounter’ totals. I however don’t have a mechanism to trigger the ‘aggregator method’ when the meters I’m interested in are updated. The aggregator method is copied below.

```
private Double aggregateValues(String idName){
    return meterRegistry.getMeters().stream()
        .filter(meter -> meter.getId().getName().startsWith(idName))
        .filter(FunctionCounter.class::isInstance)
        .map(FunctionCounter.class::cast)
        .mapToDouble(FunctionCounter::count)
        .sum();
}
```

I created a configuration bean to attempt the same, no joy

```
@Configuration
@Component
@Slf4j
public class Metrics {

    @Bean
    public FunctionCounter getAggregateCounter(MeterRegistry registry) {
        List<FunctionCounter> counters = registry.getMeters().stream().
            filter(meter -> meter.getId().getName().
                startsWith("Output_Message_Count"))
            .filter( FunctionCounter.class::isInstance )
            .map(FunctionCounter.class::cast)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        FunctionCounter counter = FunctionCounter
                .builder("Combined_Output_Message_Count", counters, state -> state.stream().mapToDouble(FunctionCounter::count).sum())
                .description("a description of what this counter does")
                .tags("region", "test")
                .register(registry);
        return counter;
    }
}
```

An example of the raw data output from actuator/prometheus endpoint os listed below

```
# HELP kafka_stream_thread_task_created_total The total number of newly created tasks
# TYPE kafka_stream_thread_task_created_total counter
kafka_stream_thread_task_created_total{kafka_version="2.7.1",spring_id="stream-builder-process",thread_id="sainsburys.applications.sc-dis.price-specification-acl-e0e5af91-ce55-4e0c-998d-269b9c6bade0-StreamThread-4",} 5.0
kafka_stream_thread_task_created_total{kafka_version="2.7.1",spring_id="stream-builder-process",thread_id="sainsburys.applications.sc-dis.price-specification-acl-e0e5af91-ce55-4e0c-998d-269b9c6bade0-StreamThread-3",} 5.0
kafka_stream_thread_task_created_total{kafka_version="2.7.1",spring_id="stream-builder-process",thread_id="sainsburys.applications.sc-dis.price-specification-acl-e0e5af91-ce55-4e0c-998d-269b9c6bade0-StreamThread-2",} 5.0
kafka_stream_thread_task_created_total{kafka_version="2.7.1",spring_id="stream-builder-process",thread_id="sainsburys.applications.sc-dis.price-specification-acl-e0e5af91-ce55-4e0c-998d-269b9c6bade0-StreamThread-1",} 5.0
```

The end goal is to have a meter that consolidates the totals as they are updated, in the case of the raw data shown above, 20
There has been talk of this work being done in the following proposal but it hasn’t progressed beyond the initial proposal stage
The proposal can be viewed at. The following url :
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-674%3A+Metric+Reporter+to+Aggregate+Metrics+in+Kafka+Streams

Answer (score 0):

This sort of aggregation should happen on the reporting side. For example, in Prometheus (which it appears you are using) you would write a query that would aggregate them automatically:

```
kafka_stream_thread_task_created_total
```

Alternatively, if your end goal is to discard a label like `thread_id` then you could use a `MeterFilter` to drop that label so all those counters are treated as the same counter.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest writing a query on the level of Prometheus instead of writing java codes.